# A little double-linked list puzzle

Tags: c++, puzzle

### Disclaimer

So initially when I posted this, it was a forward list by my error even though I meant to do it as a double-linked list - that's why there are some replies that don't match the problem.

### Problem

I was doing some coding and I got to code below. At first glance, it looked like there is nothing wrong with the code, but there is a logical flaw. Can you find it?

```
class Node {
  int val;
  Node *next, *prev;

 public: 
  Node(int val, Node *prev, Node *next) {
    this->val = val;
    this->prev= prev;
    this->next = next;
  }
  int get() {return val;}
  Node* getNext() {return next;}
  Node* getPrev() {return prev;}
};

int main() {
  Node *n1, *n2, *n3;
  n1 = new Node(1, NULL, n2);
  n2 = new Node(2, n1, n3);
  n3 = new Node(3, n2, NULL);

  Node *next = n1;
  while (next != NULL) {
    cout << next->get() << endl;
    next = next->getNext();
  }
}
```

> The problem is that pointers n1, n2, n3 will get the right addresses only after the memory is allocated with operator **new**. That means addresses of these pointers are not the same upon Node class instantiation. Eg. in line `n2 = new Node(2, n1, n3);` n3 would be a bad pointer (because the memory has not been allocated jet and is currently pointing to some nonsense).

### Question

Fixing the problem is not an issue, but it made me wonder:

1. Can you find a way of fixing it without adding any new attribute or method to the class Node?
2. To go a step further, can you find a way of fixing it without changing any code inside the class Node?

### My take on it

> To the first question, I thought of the quickest solution. I just made attributes next and prev pointers to pointers and changed the code so that it passes references to the constructor. Also had to change the syntax of the while loop to get dereferenced values.

> To the second question, we got one possible solution in replies. We can simply make an array of Nodes. This way we know the exact address of each member as *n*-th member of an array will have an address of the first member + *n* - 1;

Comment: This probably belongs in Code Golf:  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com.  You can user your account from here to log on.  This is for problems you need help with - though puzzles are always intriguing :)

Comment: Why not keep `Node` code intact and just initialize them in the dependency order? I.e. `n3 = new Node(3, NULL); n2 = new Node(2, n3); n1 = new Node(1, n2);`

Comment: "and save addresses to n1, n2, n3 before we initialize classes"  you might want to search for placement new. See e.g https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: Don't do this (it works however) - `n1 = new Node(1, new Node(2, new Node(3, NULL)));`

Comment: The question (at least part 2.) seems on-topic, but this is not really an appropriate format for questions on SO. I'd suggest removing the `spoiler` bits, and making the whole question sound less like a puzzle.

Comment: I'm seeing `error: variable 'n2' is uninitialized when used here` because it is uninitialized.  I turn on my compiler warnings and treat them as errors.  Now I'll read the spoilers.

Comment: Why the spoiler tags? If you have a question, why make people work to get all the information. I'd call it inconsiderate at best.

Comment: Just use `std::list<int>` and you can't make that happen

Comment: @JamesKing You are right, this would be more appropriate for Code Golf, but I don't know if it is possible to move the post there unless reposting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Eg. in line n2 = new Node(2, n3); n3 would be a bad pointer

There is a simple solution. Fix the order of initialisation so that you start with objects that have no dependencies, and initialise objects after their dependencies have been initialised. In this case, "1" depends on "2" and "2" depends on "3", so therefore:

```
n3 = new Node(3, nullptr);
n2 = new Node(2, n3);
n1 = new Node(1, n2);
```

> Is it possible to allocate memory in advance?

Sure. It is possible to allocate memory. If you allocate memory before doing something else, then you are allocating memory in advance of that something.

You could create all of the nodes in one go by using an array. You don't even need any dynamic allocation:

```
Node nodes[] {
    {1, nodes + 1},
    {2, nodes + 2},
    {3, nullptr},
};
Node* next = nodes;
```

---

P.S.

- I recommend against bare owning pointers. Your example leaks memory.
- Don't use `NULL` in C++. It has been obsoleted by `nullptr`.
- For whatever reason, you've forgotten to initialise the `prev` member.

Comment: I just want to notify you that I've corrected a big mistake in my initial post so your reply may need a bit of updating too. Please don't be mad. Your solution with an array is so out-of-the-box great!

Answer (score 0):

I think changing to use pointers-to-pointers is a very very bad idea, and would be extremely odd.

The easist way to do this is to build the tree in reverse:

```
Node * n3 = new Node(3, nullptr);
Node * n2 = new Node(2, n3);
Node * n1 = new Node(1, n2);
```

This eliminates n1 using n2 before n2 is created.

However, you still have a problem. At no point are you managing prev. So you might want to do this:

Node(int val, Node *next) {
this->val = val;
this->next = next;

```
 // Add these lines.
 if (next != nullptr) {
     next->prev = this;
 }
```

}

Note also that using NULL to reference an uninitialized pointer is very old-style C. If you're going to program modern C++, please use nullptr instead, as you see in my examples.

I also did one more change different from yours. I personally don't like this code:

```
Node *n1, *n2, *n3;
```

I dislike it for two reasons, both of which will be referenced in at least *some* corporate style guides. First, some style guides will tell you to reference only one variable per line, not three, like you have. And also, some guides will warn you against leaving your pointers uninitialized. So I broke it out, as you see in my example above.

This last part is just style, but I can't tell you the number of bugs I've chased down due to one or the others of these. For instance, this can hide:

```
Node *n1, n2, *n3;
```

Depending on your font size, the sharpness of your eyes, and the phase of moon, you might not see that n2 isn't declared as a pointer. Now, modern compilers will probably catch bad usage, but still... Also, if you agree that all variables should be initialized to something reasonable when created, then your code can get lengthy, and it can be easy to not see you didn't initialize everything.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a reply to my question. You were right, I was not managing the prev pointer. Initially, when I posted the question, I meant to write a double-linked list but was tired and forgot to include it in the rest of the code. I took the time and edited the original question to include it. Thank you for the advice regarding the null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to create a doubly linked list. The bug is you have passed null inside the constructor as an argument. This can be resolved if you allocate memory in the following order:

```
Node *n3=new Node(3,NULL);
Node *n2=new Node(2,n3)
Node *n1=new Node(1,n2)
Node *next=n1
while(next!=NULL){
  cout<<next->get();
  next=next->getNext();
}
```

Comment: That's right, I wanted to do it as a double-linked list but forgot to include it in my code. Just wanted to let you know I've corrected the mistake in my initial post. Thank you.